# Class groups of normal domains over finite fields

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry, characteristic-p

Let R be a local, normal domain of dimension 2. Suppose that R contains a finite field. I am interested in knowing when the class group of R is torsion. In characteristic 0, this is known to be related to R being a rational singularity.

Lipman showed that if X is a desingularization of Spec(R), then one has an exact sequence:

$0 \to Pic^{0}(X) \to Cl(R) \to H $

Here $Pic^{0}(X)$ is the numerically trivial part of the Picard group of $X$, and $H$ is a finite group. Thus the second one is torsion if and only if the first one is. I do not have much understanding of the first group, unfortunately.

Does anyone know an answer or reference to this? Does anyone know an example in positive characteristic such that $Cl(R)$ is not torsion? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I was going to point you to this nice paper I read recently about Frobenius and torsion in the class group ... then I saw who the poster was!

Comment: Hi Graham! Yes, unfortunately we need dimension 3! I think a general answer is probably not easy, but there are many smart people here. 

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As requested in the comments, here's an example of a local, normal $2$-dimensional domain R in positive characteristic such that $\mathrm{Cl}(R)$ is not torsion: choose an elliptic curve $E \subset \mathbf{P}^2$ over a field $k$ such that $E(k)$ is not torsion, and take R to be the local ring at the origin of the affine cone on $E$ (i.e., $R  = k[x,y,z]/(f)_{(x,y,z)}$ where $f$ is a homoegenous cubic defining $E$). This can be done over $k = \overline{\mathbf{F}_p(t)}$.

*Proof*: The normality follows from the fact that R is a hypersurface singularity (hence even Gorenstein) and isolated and $2$-dimensional (hence regular in codim 1). Blowing up at the origin defines a map $f:X \to \mathrm{Spec}(R)$. One can then show the following: $X$ is smooth, and $X$ can be identified with the Zariski localisation along the zero section of the total space of the line bundle $L = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{P^2}}(-1)|_E$ (these are general facts about cones). By Lipman's theorem, it suffices to show that $\mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$ contains non-torsion elements. As $X$ is fibered over $E$ with a section, the pullback $\mathrm{Pic}^0(E) \to \mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$ is a direct summand. As $\mathrm{Pic}^0(E) \simeq E(k)$ has non-torsion elements by assumption, so does $\mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$.

Also, an additional comment: In general, Lipman's theorem tells you that $\mathrm{Cl}(R)$ is torsion if and only if $\mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$ is torsion. Now $\mathrm{Pic}(X) \simeq \lim_n \mathrm{Pic}(X_n)$ where $X_n$ is the $n$-th order thickening of the exceptional fibre $E$. Because we are blowing up a point, the sheaf of ideals $I$ defining $E$ is ample on $E$. The kernel and cokernel of $\mathrm{Pic}(X_n) \to \mathrm{Pic}(X_{n-1})$ are identified with $H^1(E,I|_E^{\otimes n+1})$ and $H^2(E,I|_E^{\otimes n+1})$. As $I|_E$ is ample, it follows that the system "$\lim_n \mathrm{Pic}(X_n)$" is eventually stable. Thus, $\mathrm{Pic}(X) \simeq \mathrm{Pic}(X_n)$ for $n$ sufficiently big. As $X_n$ is a proper variety, it follows that if we are working over a finite field (resp. an algebraic closure of a finite field), then $\mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$ is finite (resp. ind-finite).

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Is there a reference about your fact on elliptic curves over big fields? 

Comment: Also, why $X_n$ proper implies $Pic^0$ finite?  

Comment: Take any old elliptic curve E over F_q, and view it as an elliptic curve E' = E \times_{F_q} k over its function field k = k(E). The generic point in E'(k) will be non-torsion (as all the torsion is defined over F_q-bar). 

Comment: The connected component $\mathrm{Pic}^0(Y)$ of the Picard group $\mathrm{Pic}(Y)$ is representable by a group scheme of finite type when Y is a proper variety, so its F_q-points form a finite set. (For spaces like the X_n appearing above, the finiteness follows from that of $\mathrm{Pic}^0(X_0)$ using the description of the kernel and cokernel I mentioned in the answer).

Comment: Beautiful! I wish I can upvote more. Please upvote this answer, this is really what MO is about. 

Comment: Is MO really about upvoting?

Comment: Dear Idoneal, I meant the answer, in my opinion, captures what MO is about.

Answer (score 2):

I recently found some references: Theorem 4.5 of  [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6WH2-4CWYY9T-HT&_user=10&_coverDate=06%2F30%2F1975&_alid=1168943407&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_cdi=6838&_sort=r&_docanchor=&view=c&_ct=1&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=80ce7ac14ec803da3335ca133a2221db)  and Theorem 4 + next Corollary of  [this paper](http://www.springerlink.com/content/g48k6345752803mr/)  which says:

If $(R,m,k)$ is a complete normal local domain of dimension $2$ such that $k$ is the algebraic closure of some finite field, then $Cl(R)$ is torsion!

It remains open what happens in other situations.

Comment: You mean only the case $k=\mathbb F_q$  remains? This case follows from the case $\overline{F}_p$ at once, I think. But what if $k$ is algebraically closed and not equal to $\mathbb F_p$?

Comment: Why would the $F_p$ follow? The class group may get smaller if one enlarge the field. But my comment was not very clear, thanks for pointing it out  

Comment: The statement will not be true for big fields k. Take the (completed) affine cone Y on an elliptic curve E in P^2 over k. Blowing up at the origin resolution X -> Y. On the other hand, X is the total space of O(-1) over E (suitably completed). In particular, Pic^0(X) contains Pic^0(E) =~ E(k) as a subgroup, and this can certainly have non-torsion elements if k is not algebraic over the prime field.

Comment: @bhargav: would you write up your answer? I want to upvote it. 

Comment: The links to `sciencedirect.com` and `springerlink.com` both appear to be broken. Perhaps you could take a look, whenever possible...